# Making a list of functions

Tags: function-construction, vector

Suppose I have the following equation system to solve:

```
x(t_):={x1(t),x2(t)};
DSolve[x'(t)==x(t),x(t),t]
```

This code works fine, but now suppose that instead of 2 unknown functions (`x1` and `x2`) I have 1000. It is impractical to declare `x(t_):={x1(t), x2(t),..., x1000(t)`.

So, the question is: How can I define `x(t)` as an array of 1000 unknown functions?

Comment: Just a reminder: *Mathematica* uses square brackets for function arguments, so your code won't work, as is, if you paste it in a notebook.

Comment: `NDSolve[]` is capable of dealing with vector-valued equations.

Comment: @jlpedro, note about `x[t_] := Through[Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 1000}][t]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Table` to declare the functions

```
x[t_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 1, 2}]
DSolve[x'[t] == x[t], x[t], t]
```

Comment: Great. Elegant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) then

```
x[t_] := Table[
  ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]]
  , {i, 1, 10}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this simple case it should work.

```
Clear[x, X]

n = 10;

Format[x[m_Integer]] := Subscript[x, m]

X[t_] := Array[x[#][t] &, n]

DSolve[D[X[t], t] == X[t], X[t], t]
```

[image]